# Proper way to call multiple functions using SP.SOD.executeFunc

Tags: 2013, javascript, development, client-object-model, sp.sod

I need to make sure **sp.js** is loaded before I call several functions.  I currently call them as follows in SP 2013.  It works, but I suspect there is a better/more efficient way.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getCurrUser);
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', evalGroups);
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getDeptMgrs);
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getItemOwner);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I normally follow as below

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', readyFunction);

function readyFunction() {
    getCurrUser();
    evalGroups();
    getDeptMgrs();
    getItemOwner();
}
```

Its more readable!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, SP.SOD.executeFunc does not work for me in my SP 2010 environment (I also can't RegisterSOD), but this works nicely. I like the cleanliness of Amal's answer):

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(readyFunction, "sp.js");

function readyFunction() {
    retrieveWebSite();
    runCode();
    other();
}
```